# How to url encode in jekyll liquid?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I have problem that categories are not url encoded when I use german words with Umlauts (e.g. ä, ü). I tried the cgi_escape that Liquid seems to offer, but success with the following code:

```
<strong>Kategorien</strong><br/>
{% for category in site.categories  do %}
  <small><a href="/categories/{{ category[0] | cgi_escape }}">{{ category[0] }} </a><br/>
         </small>    
{% endfor %}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: what does the link look like now? `/categories/eichhörnchen` ?

Comment: Yes: it looks like categories/eichhörnchen

Comment: and you want `eichh%C3%B6rnchen` or something like that?

Comment: Yes that is what I expected when using the _cgi_escape_ . At the moment I get an g error message (invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII ) if I click on the /categories/eichhörnchen link.

Comment: But it could also be another problem. Files seem to be created, but only Webrick is throwing an error: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII  // WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2012-04-20) at 0.0.0.0:4000

Answer (score 7):

Using `cgi_escape` doesn't work correctly for categories with spaces.  Links were generated as `/category/the+category` instead of `/category/the%20category`.

The solution I ended up using was from <del>[this blog post](http://blog.akciom.com/2013/01/11/setting-up-jekyll/)</del>:

```
# _plugins/url_encode.rb
require 'liquid'
require 'uri'

# Percent encoding for URI conforming to RFC 3986.
# Ref: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-12
module URLEncoding
  def url_encode(url)
    return URI.escape(url, Regexp.new("[^#{URI::PATTERN::UNRESERVED}]"))
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(URLEncoding)
```

A plus is a literal plus anywhere but in the query portion of the URL, where it represents a space.  <del>[Good URL encoding reference](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding)</del> ([archive.org mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20151229061347/http://blog.lunatech.com:80/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding)).

This can then be used in a layout or anywhere else:

```
<a href="{{ site.category_dir }}/{{ category | url_encode }}">
```

Comment: The blog post is not accessible anymore.

Comment: @jcubic Do you think I should remove the link?  I quoted the important part just for such an eventuality.

Comment: You can wrap the lines in `<strike></strike>` you can also put `{{ url | url_encode }}` so it's obvious how to use the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

@Peterb, have you upgraded to the latest version of Jekyll? The current 1.0x version supports UTF-8 and handles URLs like this much better.

You can install the latest version by running this from your Terminal command line:

`$ [sudo] gem install jekyll --pre`

This GitHub Issue post will shed more light on the issue:
https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/960